# MySQL Workbench skip pulling schema list on opening a SQL editor

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to make the Workbench skip caching the schema information on SQL Editor load? I've got tons of tables in my database (not to mention the server is half way across the world) and it takes ages to fire up the SQL Editor.

This would be something akin to --skip-auto-rehash (or the -A switch) on the command line but for the life of me I couldn't find anything on the Workbench or connection options to do this.